# Updating intl-tel-input plugin doesn't return input value

Tags: angularjs, country-codes, intl-tel-input

We are using intl-tel-input plugin in AngularJS(v1.5) to show countries list along with country code. We have updated this plugin and added new entry [in this array](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input/blob/master/build/js/intlTelInput.js#L28) as "No country" and set this entry as default in the drop down.

Now when user selects this default value, "No country", and submits the form, we are not getting phone number value entered by user. This seems binding issue.

Can someone please help to get value from this input field.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.